# Erro ao baixar PDF no Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Criei uma página para fazer download de arquivos PDF. Nele incluí o seguinte código:

`<a href="https://revistamovimentto.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/Movimentto-Edição-88.pdf" download>
<img class="alignnone wp-image-291 size-medium" src="https://revistamovimentto.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/capa88-222x300.png" alt="" width="222" height="300" />
</a>`

Ele cria uma imagem que ao ser clicada, deveria baixar o PDF `https://revistamovimentto.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/Movimentto-Edição-88.pdf`

Porém, ao clicar no link, dá erro de página não encontrada ao invés de baixar o arquivo. E a url está ok de acordo com o arquivo de mídia.

Comment: Já verificou no arquivos do servidor se o PDF ta lá? experimente usar nomes sem acentos.

Comment: O erro era devido aos acentos mesmos. Obrigado

Comment: tente apenas assim e se funcionar o problema nao esta no link!! `<a href="https://revistamovimentto.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/Movimentto-Edição-88.pdf" download></a>
`